# I have a data base full of codes and I want to call this data by when it was submitted

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I'm relatively new to coding but I have a table w/ over 1000 codes in it.

Well, when people submit new information to it (via submit form) I want to be able to add the date/time to the table so that when I can print the 'latest 25'.

My questions are:

How do I add a column for the time?  How do I add the time function to my submit line in my html?  Will I get screwed because I'm going to have 1000 rows w/o a date and then whatever new rows w/ a date?

Comment: Consider reviewing one of the tutorials available on the web, like this one: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a DATETIME column.  Allow Nulls
2. Your existing records will have a null in the new column.  This is OK.
3. Use a query like this to get your top 25 records:

   SELECT column1, column2
   FROM table
   ORDER BY MyDateTimeColumn DESC
   LIMIT 25

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the new datetime column to default to a certain value (namely the current date/time) or you can include it in your insert statement.

```
insert into table (col1, col2, datetime_col) values ('whatever', 'whatever', now())
```

This is untested but would work in SQL Server...i imagine it would work in MySQL as well (actually the function in SQL Server is getdate() and a quick google search tells me that it is now() in MySQL).